# ServiceStack Razor - How to Return Validation Errors to a Form?

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to use ServiceStack Razor for old-fashioned server-side form validation.

By way of example: a GET to a url returns a razor template with a form. When the user POSTs the form, request DTO is validated and if there were errors, the user is shown the same form, with original values re-populated as and fields in error marked somehow. If, on the other hand the request DTO is valid, the service will redirect the user to another page.

Is that scenario possible?

If so, how would one go about implementing it? I presume I'll have to write certain filters or features for this to work, however I'm wondering what strategy will require minimum amount of coding.

(I understand javascript validation is possible, however my question is specifically whether it is possible to round-trip the form with server-side validation).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at ss-validation.js, it can be used to apply validation errors to your form based on ServiceStack's ResponseStatus.

So we write all our validation code server side using FluentValidation, then on round trip ss-validation reads ResponseStatus and applies markup.

Out of the box is assumes Bootstrap style validation, but it's fairly easy to modify to suit your needs, e.g. we amended to display inline icon tool tips instead of inline/block messages, and provide an error summary.

Comment: Hey Gavin, thanks for your reply. I am looking specifically for old-skool posting back to the server and reloading the form, sans any js. The current master (v3.9.44) does not support what I need - validation errors short-circuit the service execution, and the response does not provide the request DTO with posted values. I've written a patch that resolves this and will hopefully submit a pull request sometimes this week after I try my solution in practice for a few days.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of spelunking of the ServiceStack codebase, it seems it is theoretically possible to achieve the desired scenario.

The code already contains `ModelMetadata` and `ModelMetadataProviders` classes, and some of the HTML helpers are ported from `System.Web.Mvc`.

Sadly, the classes are not fully wired, so I guess it will require solid amount of work to get everything working correctly as one would expect.